# JS function call replaced by another

Tags: javascript

I have a weird issue where one of my functions (removeTransition) is ignored and another is called (addTransition). What is going on here?

added a snippet to question instead of external `codepen`:

```js
   const example = document.querySelector('#myExample');

    function addTransition () {
      example.classList.add('transition');
      console.log('addTransition',example);
    }

    function removeTransition () {
      example.classList.remove('transition');
      console.log('removeTransition',example);
    }

    const el = document.querySelector('.example');
    const output = document.querySelector('#output');

    el.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
      output.textContent = 'Transition ended'; 
    });

    document.addEventListener('click', addTransition);
```

```css
 .example {
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      background: pink;
      transition-property: transform background;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      transition-delay: 1s;
    }

    .transition {
      background: cyan;
      width: 200px;
    }

    .transition::after {
      content: 'Transition class added'
    }
```

```html
    <div id="myExample" class="example"></div>
    <br>
    <button onClick="addTransition">Add</button>
    <button onClick="removeTransition">Remove</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Your `onclick` attributes are wrong, they should be *calling* a function, not just referencing a function. (Then your `document.addEventListener('click', addTransition);` calls `addTransition` regardless.) Best to avoid inline handlers entirely

Comment: Oh, I see. Not only did I forget the event listener for removeTrasition, I generalised it, so any click on the document triggers the function call. Even on the element itself, I can still only use one click event, so would have to add maybe a toggle instead. I'm not sure what this inline handler terminology is though. I will google it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on:

1. Old-style `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers need to **call** the function, not just refer to it. So you'd need `()` on these:

   ```
   <button onClick="addTransition">Add</button>
   <!--                          ^---- missing ()    -->
   <button onClick="removeTransition">Remove</button>
   <!--                             ^---- missing () -->
   ```
2. You're calling `addTransition` when there's a click anywhere in the document:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('click', addTransition)
   ```

To fix it:

1. Don't use attribute-style even thandlers.
2. Hook up your handlers using `addEventListener`.
3. Have them stop propagation of the event.
4. Remove the handler you have on `document`(?). I'm not sure what it's meant to be for.

Something like this:

```js
const example = document.querySelector('#myExample');

function addTransition() {
    example.classList.add('transition');
    console.log('addTransition', example);
}

function removeTransition() {
    example.classList.remove('transition');
    console.log('removeTransition', example);
}

const el = document.querySelector('.example');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

el.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    output.textContent = 'Transition ended';
});

document.querySelector("button.add").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  addTransition();
});
document.querySelector("button.remove").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  removeTransition();
});

// Possibly remove this?
document.addEventListener('click', addTransition);
```

```css
.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  transition-property: transform background;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.transition {
  background: cyan;
  width: 200px;
}

.transition::after {
  content: 'Transition class added'
}
```

```html
<div id="myExample" class="example"></div>
<br>
<button class="add">Add</button>
<button class="remove">Remove</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

You *can* do it with those attribute handlers if you really want to, though:

```js
const example = document.querySelector('#myExample');

function addTransition() {
    example.classList.add('transition');
    console.log('addTransition', example);
}

function removeTransition() {
    example.classList.remove('transition');
    console.log('removeTransition', example);
}

const el = document.querySelector('.example');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

el.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    output.textContent = 'Transition ended';
});

// Possibly remove this?
document.addEventListener('click', addTransition);
```

```css
.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  transition-property: transform background;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.transition {
  background: cyan;
  width: 200px;
}

.transition::after {
  content: 'Transition class added'
}
```

```html
<div id="myExample" class="example"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="addTransition(); event.stopPropagation();">Add</button>
<button onclick="removeTransition(); event.stopPropagation();">Remove</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

But I don't recommend it, not least because your functions have to be globals, and avoiding globals is a Good Thing™. ;-)